# Добавления TextView в Button

Tags: android, button, android-intent, textview

Мне надо добавить текст из TExtView в Button. о/Объясняю ситуацию ,я взял данные из первого активити которые были введены с помощью Edittext и с помощью Intent перевел их на вторую активность. Во второй активности я вывел их через TextView. и для перехода на третью активность у меня есть кнопка в которой должен быть текст из этого Text View. То есть на второй активности у меня будет одна строка с TextView и одна кнопка в которой должен быть такой же текст как и в строке. Проблема заключается в том что я не могу вписать просто текст в кнопку так как он меняется когда на первой активности изменяют Edittext, как мне сделать содержание текста такое же как и TExtView

Comment: Точно так же как и в `TextView`: `button.setText(yourText)`

Comment: а могу я как-то добавить перед этим текстом еще свой текст ,чтобы он был постоянно и просто добавлялся тот, который с intent'a (например: слово "номер" всегда бы был, а сам номер добавлялся бы

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings